# Sandboxing exceptions (of external libraries & the std::lib)

Tags: c++, exception

I have watched [Mike Acton's talk on *Data-Oriented Design and C++*](https://youtu.be/rX0ItVEVjHc?t=8m30s).
As he stated at 8min30sec that they don't use exceptions, they cannot  force it to be off on third party libraries. Therefore they "sandbox around" these libraries.

My questions are:

**1.**
What is exactly meant by "sandboxing around" libraries using exceptions, when my codebase runs with disabled exceptions and how does it work and how do I do that? (are there differences on platforms (Win/Linux/Mac, consoles or mobile?)

**2.** When using the standard library (which uses exceptions, as in `new` and the alikes) how I "sandbox" them - or is it the same principle as in 1.?

Comment: Just watch the rest of the video, he goes on to explain how they don't use the normal heap, i.e. the is no `new`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm going to use the standard library, and not all std implementations seem to support disabled exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can sandbox the exception by just caching it in a wrapper. Let's suppose you have:

- a third party library `T` that DOES use exceptions
- your application `A` that DOES NOT use exceptions.

You then create a wrapper `W` (compiled WITH exceptions enabled) that will wrap `T` but catch all exceptions wherever it exists and, for example, replace by and error code, like this:

```
// this one comes from the original library T that throws exceptions
void someFunctionInT();

// this will be your wrapper around the function above
int someFunctionInW()
{
    try
    {
        someFunctionInT();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, this way, your wrapper `W` should NOT throw any exception and you can use safely link against your application `A`.

Obviously, this is just a simple example. But you can do something a little "fancier" once at this time you already "paid" for the exception handling. For example, you can test the exception and return different error codes or prepare an error message to be retrieved from another function, etc, etc... up to your creativity. :-)